how to avoid the "Type conversion in expression" when using HASHBYTES
I have this query:
declare @password nvarchar(254) ='R0nald0$123456.', 
@username nvarchar(50)='Ronaldo',
@playerId uniqueidentifier,
@userType int;

declare @UserUsername_CS int =CHECKSUM(@username);

    SELECT Top 1 @playerId = [UserId]
      FROM [dbo].[UsersPrivate]
     WHERE [UserUsername_CS] =  @UserUsername_CS    
       And [UserUsername]   = @username                
       AND [UserPassword]   = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT([Salt], @password));

select @playerId

It generates the right result; however, I am not sure I am using the "best way" to do this when comparing the user's password with the provided password via the hash.
As [Salt] is part of the table, I can't pre-glue them to get a Binary(32) variable. I have the following index:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_UsersPrivate_UserName_UserPassword] ON [dbo].[UsersPrivate]
(
    [UserUsername_CS] ASC,
    [UserUsername] ASC,
    [UserPassword] ASC  
)

, which is ignored by the execution plan.

Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(8),
[ClubStat].[dbo].[UsersPrivate].[Salt],0)) may affect
"CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

Here is the execution plan: Past the plan
This is the table definition:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersPrivate](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserPassword] [binary](32) NOT NULL,
    [UserUsername] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserUsername_CS]  AS (checksum([UserUsername])) PERSISTED,
    [Salt] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersPrivate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)

I use this to generate the PW and Salt:
DECLARE @salt BINARY(16) = CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16) AS BINARY(16));

-- Compute the hash
DECLARE @hashedPassword BINARY(32);
SET @hashedPassword = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT(@salt, CAST(@password AS VARBINARY(510))));


Try changing UserPassword from being part of the key to being an included column.

Please show the full definition of the table. I'd guess Salt is varchar not nvarchar. As to performance: UserName should b unique anyway so the extra predicates make little difference to perf. Why does Username need a checksum? SQL Server is perfectly capable of doing a normal BTree lookup on it.

@Charlieface, the checksum comes from  a Microsoft recommendation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 where one uses a CS to speedup an index

"This can help improve indexing speed when the column to index is a long character column." it's only useful if the length is very long, too big to be indexed, otherwise it's a waste of time. B-Tree indexes are very efficient, and nvarchar(50) is just not wide enough to be worrying about.

CONCAT returns a string, so it's implicitly converting the @salt and @password to varchar. Instead, use + to concat varbinary values.
SET @hashedPassword = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @salt + CAST(@password AS VARBINARY(510)));

Note that in general you should hash the password on the client-side, not the server. The salt is not private and can be passed to the client. A commmon design is to use the username itself as the salt.
Also, your unique index should be over UserUsername, and Password should be an INCLUDE.
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_UsersPrivate_UserName_UserPassword] ON dbo.UsersPrivate
(UserUsername) INCLUDE (UserPassword, Salt)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);

The username hash is unnecessary as I mentioned in comments, because the column it's hashing isn't wide enough to gain anything, you should just index that directly.
